# Kafka connect JDBC error despite giving schema and payload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jdbc-postgres

I am getting the following error when I run kafka JDBC connector to PSQL:

> JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload"
> fields and may not  contain additional fields. If you are trying to
> deserialize plain JSON data, set  schemas.enable=false in your
> converter configuration.

However my topic contains the following message structure with a schema added just like its presented online:

> rowtime: 2022/02/04 12:45:48.520 Z, key: , value: "{"**schema**":
> {"type": "struct", "fields": [{"type": "int", "field":
> "ID", "optional": false}, {"type": "date", "field":
> "Date", "optional": false}, {"type": "varchar",
> "field": "ICD", "optional": false}, {"type": "int",
> "field": "CPT", "optional": false}, {"type": "double",
> "field": "Cost", "optional": false}], "optional": false,
> "name": "test"}, "**payload**": {"ID": "24427934",
> "Date": "2019-05-22", "ICD": "883.436", "CPT":
> "60502", "cost": "1374.36"}}",
> partition: 0

My configuration for the connector is:

```
 curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/claim_test/config \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
     "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
     "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ae2772",
     "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
     "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
     "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
     "topics":"test_7",
     "auto.create":"true",
     "insert.mode":"insert"
    }'
```

After some changes, I now get the following message:

`WorkerSinkTask{id=claim_test} Error converting message value in topic 'test_9' partition 0 at offset 0 and timestamp 1644005137197: Unknown schema type: int`

Comment: Have you checked _all_ the messages in your topic follow this format?

Comment: Yes - i have deleted previous topics and the current topic has a producer publishing json messages from python. The structure of the messages is all consistent.

Comment: I know get the following message:  WorkerSinkTask{id=claim_test} Error converting message value in topic 'test_9' partition 0 at offset 0 and timestamp 1644005137197: Unknown schema type: int - any help here would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is not a valid schema type. Should be `int8`, `int16`,  `int32`, or `int64`.

Similarly, `date`, `varchar` and `double` are not valid either.

The types used in the JSON are not the same as Postgres or any SQL-specific types (a date should be converted to a Unix Epoch `int64` time or be made a `string`).

You can find the supported schema types here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Schema.java